# How can i change the Display type of a sublist field in a beforeLoad function?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

Im trying to set the display type of a sublist field when the user is creating/viewing/editing an record.

This is for an Netsuite customization.

```
define(['N/ui/serverWidget'], function (serverWidget) {
    function beforeLoad(serverWidget) {

        if (scriptContext.type == scriptContext.UserEventType.VIEW || 
scriptContext.type == scriptContext.UserEventType.EDIT || 
scriptContext.type == scriptContext.UserEventType.CREATE) {
            var form = serverWidget.createForm({
                title: 'Movile - Requisition Costs Analyst'
            });

            var nomeFornecedor = form.getSublist({ id: 'item' }).getField({
                id: 'vendorname'
            });
            nomeFornecedor.isDisabled = false;
        }


    }
    return { beforeLoad: beforeLoad }
})
```

I expect to learn how to do that type of sublist editing.

Any help are apreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
define(['N/ui/serverWidget'], function (serverWidget) {
    function beforeLoad(context) {

        if (context.type == scriptContext.UserEventType.VIEW || context.type == scriptContext.UserEventType.EDIT || context.type == scriptContext.UserEventType.CREATE) {
            var form = context.form;
            form.title = 'Movile - Requisition Costs Analyst';
            var nomeFornecedor = form.getSublist({ id: 'item' }).getField({
                id: 'vendorname'
            });
            nomeFornecedor.updateDisplayType({displayType: serverWidget.FieldDisplayType.DISABLED});
        }
    }
    return { beforeLoad: beforeLoad }
})
```

Comment: Been searching for an answer for a while. Thanks man!